# How to extract multiple values from a NumericVector in C++

Tags: c++, r, indexing, rcpp

I'm quite a newbie to `Rcpp` and its functionalities, not to mention C++ per se, so this might probably seem trivial to the experts among you. However, there's no such thing as a stupid question, so anyway:

I was wondering if there was a method to address multiple elements of a NumericVector in C++ at once using indexing. To make the whole thing more clear, here's the R equivalent of what I'm trying to do:

```
# Initial vector
x <- 1:10

# Extract the 2nd, 5th and 8th element of the vector
x[c(2, 5, 8)]
[1] 2 5 8
```

This is what I got so far in the C++ function that I'm executing in R using `sourceCpp`. It works, but it seems quite inconvenient to me. Is there any easier way to achieve my goals?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector subsetNumVec(NumericVector x, IntegerVector index) {  
  // Length of the index vector
  int n = index.size();
  // Initialize output vector
  NumericVector out(n);

  // Subtract 1 from index as C++ starts to count at 0
  index = index - 1; 
  // Loop through index vector and extract values of x at the given positions
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    out[i] = x[index[i]];
  }

  // Return output
  return out;
}

/*** R
  subsetNumVec(1:10, c(2, 5, 8))
*/
>   subsetNumVec(1:10, c(2, 5, 8))
[1] 2 5 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you use Armadillo vectors, rather than Rcpp vectors.

The [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) has a [post with a complete example](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/armadillo-subsetting/): see in particular the second example.  Your indexing entries have to be in a (unsigned) `uvec` or `umat`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no shorter way!

But your `NumericVector subsetNumVec(NumericVector x, IntegerVector index)` is error-prone:

Within this line

```
out[i] = x[index[i]];
```

you access the vector without range-checking. So in the trivial case the `x` is empty or the index is out-of-range, you get some undefined behavior.

Furthermore, you method can call by reference

```
NumericVector subsetNumVec(const NumericVector& x, const IntegerVector& index)
```

There is no reason to copy both vectors. You only have to move the substract `index = index -1;` to `out[i] = x.at(index[i] - 1);`

Here, `x.at(index[i] - 1)` throws on false index. But then you need some error handling (return empty vector or do the handling outside).